# PHP can't copy (exec pbcopy) to clipboard on browser, but on terminal

Tags: php, apache

I am running MAMP, my PHP Code to test:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header('content-type:text/plain');

ob_start();
echo ini_get('safe_mode') ? 'safe' : 'not safe';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo exec('whoami').PHP_EOL;
echo exec('groups').PHP_EOL;
echo exec('which pbcopy').PHP_EOL;
$str = 'teststr'.rand(0, 9999);
exec('echo "'.$str.'" | pbcopy');
$pbpaste = exec('pbpaste 2>&1');
echo $pbpaste.PHP_EOL;
echo $pbpaste == $str ? 'IT WORKS' : 'failed';
echo PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents('output.log', ob_get_contents());
```

I get the same output (like the same user and pbcopy path) on terminal and browser but on terminal it says "IT WORKS", because the execution of pbcopy and pbpaste works.

This worked before on a previous version of MAMP but after updating MAMP it doesn't work anymore.

BTW: I'm working on a webdav skript for monosnap, so actually I want it to work on monosnap but it doesn't. Monosnap is also just calling localhost....script.php so I think it's the same problem why it is not working in the browser.

FYI, output of terminal:

```
not safe
firebook
staff everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh-disabled
/usr/bin/pbcopy
teststr9794
IT WORKS
```

output in the browser

```
not safe
firebook
staff everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh-disabled
/usr/bin/pbcopy

failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, after running `.../apachectl start` manually from MAMP it worked, now I have extended exec permission and can run osascripts (e.g. display dialog) when visiting a browser page. (It works, I have no idea why exactly, I think it's not because of the binary)